# how could i combine NSString with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have `NSString*url` ,and i want to combine with NSArray of number to load the picture ,i struggle for many days still doesn't work anyone know how to do it

p.s  I want to replace NSString %@ with number of array

This is my `NSString *url = http://flicksbank.console360.net/images/%@/default.jpg`

And this is my number from NSArray :

(

```
    42,
    47,
    56,
    65,
    97,
    128,
    277,
    278,
    312,
    313,
    518,
    522,
    523,
    526
),
    (
    42,
    89,
    522
),
    (
    89,
    312,
    313
),
    (
    89,
    522
),
    (
    91,
    317
),
    (
    98
),
    (
    317,
    518,
    523,
    525,
    526
),
    (
    329
),
    (
    332
)
```

Comment: Your `NSArray` is a `NSArray` of `NSArray` of `NSString` (or `NSNumber`). Are you looking for a "for loop", or access first one in the third group? It's unclear.

Comment: I want to every single number replace to the url but i'm not sure which way is better to achieve it

Comment: What objects are in the `NSArray`?

Comment: as he said 'NSArray of numbers', i guess they are numbers @trojanfoe

Comment: Indeed; that would make the most sense, given the log output does not contain quotes round each value.

Comment: Yes, they are number of array i took those from NSDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reach numbers with two for loops:

```
for(NSArray *numbers in yourMainArray)
{
     for(NSNumber *n in numbers)
     {
         NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://flicksbank.console360.net/images/%d/default.jpg", [n intValue]];
     }

}
```

or more general solution for `NSString` and `NSNumber`

```
    for(NSArray *numbers in yourMainArray)
    {
         for(id n in numbers)
         {
             if([n isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
             {
                 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://flicksbank.console360.net/images/%d/default.jpg", [n intValue]];
             }
              if([n isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
             {
                 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://flicksbank.console360.net/images/%@/default.jpg", n];
             }
         }

    }
```

Comment: It possible put NSString in array?!

Comment: @smiletony, Yes, you can put any object inherited from `NSObject` class.

Answer (score 0):

you have nested array , if you want to display images with all those number you have to loop through both arrays.

```
for(NSArray* mainArray in firstArray){
   for(NSString *number in mainArray){
      NSLog(@"http://flicksbank.console360.net/images/%@/default.jpg",number);
   }
}
```

Main array will be your object that you have logged.

Comment: you cant save primitives in NSArray.

Comment: now it won't give trouble coz we just need it into string

Comment: Are they `NSString` objects or `NSNumber` objects?

Comment: what every the object type is main question is the guy want to loop through the both array and he do do like this if he want, he may change the object type that he wants..that will be not an issue....is it is?@smiletonny

Comment: Yes it's an issue as it affects what messages you can send the objects.

Comment: @trojanfoe--the guys didn't specified the object type, he can modify that code according to the type he want...just let it be that simple